# Input text value in HTML script

Tags: javascript, html

When fill text in input text tag in web page, I go to inspect element, and the value of the input is empty, is there a way to make the value takes the input in html script.
The input html script after inserting test looks like this

```
<input name="test" type="text" maxlength="255" value="">
```

and I want it to be like

```
<input name="test" type="text" maxlength="255" value="test">
```

Is this possible??

Comment: what do you mean by html script??

Comment: The appearance of the element in your developers tool is not exactly the current state of the element. If you access this element with any script the correct value will be returned to you. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Why would you want to do so..?

Comment: I meant the html code <inputt type="text" .... />

Comment: I want the take the html code, and view it in another page, I did this:
 var html = $("html").html();
 var w=window.open("/paltelportal/portal/testt.php");
 w.document.write(html);

everything works fine except the input texts appears empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reflect the changes to input's value to the HTML, you have to set the `value` attribute of an input. Something like this:

```
$('#test').change(function () {
    $(this).attr('value', this.value);
});
```

Notice also, that jQuery `.html()` returns the *`innerHTML`* of `html`, hence you've to modify your string to have also starting and ending `html` tags (or use vanilla JS `outerHTML`).

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6zq26/).

Answer (score 0):

The value of `value` is what is rendered on the page load - the browser interprets what is actually written on form submit.

Why are you trying to do this? Javascript can also read the current value (without it needing to be in the HTML)

Comment: I want the take the html code, and view it in another page, I did this: var html = $("html").html(); var w=window.open("/paltelportal/portal/testt.php"); w.document.write(html); everything works fine except the input texts appears empty

Comment: @OmarTaha FYI, [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) will wipe out all the previous code from `testt.php`, everything what is left, is the argument you've written to the page. Also please put that code snippet to your question, it'll make more sense.

Comment: @Teemu , testt.php is empty page, I put it just to make the url paths works, otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score -2):

remove value in the input tag just use this

```
<input name="test" type="text" maxlength="255">
```

when you insert the value in webpage it will add value automatically.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.